# Scrolling tableview while updating its datasource fetched from CoreData crash

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data

**Here is my context:**

When I launch my app I fetch local data from CoreData and fill a tableview with it. At the same time I send an asynchronous request to my webservice to fetch what will be the new content of my tableview. 
As soon as the request sends me a response I delete all the instances of the current NSManagedObjects and create new ones with the new data I got. Then I replace the datasource of my tableview to an array of the new NSManagedObjectContexts instances.

**My problem:**

I'm getting an error : **CoreData could not fulfill a fault for ...** if I scroll my tableview when the request finished and is triggering the deletion/creation of my tableview's data source.

I understand that this problem occurs because I'm trying to access an old NSManagedObject instance while doesn't exist anymore as it is explained in the doc : [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW7). But I have no idea of what are the best practices in my case.

I don't want to block the user until my request finished but I have to prevent any error if he accesses "old" data while the request didn't finish (e.g : what if the user taps on a cell and I pass an instance of an NSManagedObject to another viewcontroller but when the request finishes this object doesn't exist anymore ?)

I would appreciate any help !

Comment: Are you using an array as the datasource of the table view or are you using NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: I'm currently an array as the datasource (actually 3 arrays as I've 3 sections) because I found it easier to manager with sections than and NSFetchedResultsController. Should I try to use an NSFetchedResultsController ?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use `NSFetchedResultsController` since it's sole purpuse is:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object.

When using a fetched results controller it is much easier to handle the Core Data events like insert, delete, update.

You say you have three sections in your table view? That's no problem, `NSFetchedResultsController` can handle all of that.

Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html). Apple provides a very nice set of instructions on how to configure and use `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I am trying to use NSFetchedResultsController but the problem is that my 3 sections are fetched on the same entity but with different sortDescriptors and predicates. So do I have to make one NSFetchedResultsController for each one of my sections ?